# Angular : How to replace hard-coded object with real time api?

Tags: angular, rest, api, angular6

**OLD Method**

> I'm new in angular. I have hard-coded object in component export class
>   which i'm using for data binding. It's working fine there.now i need
>   to replace same object with real time data.

```
newProduct: any = [
                  { product: "some1", checked: true },
                  { product: "some2", checked: false }
                  ]

 <input id="checkbox" type="checkbox" value="{{newProduct[0].product}}" [(ngModel)]="newProduct[0].checked" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}" (change)="productNotSelected()" checked /><span>{{newProduct[0].product}}</span>
```

> What i did up to now is i called API in NgOninit method and getting
>   response properly. Here is the function which i'm calling on
>   NgOninit.This gives me error like undefined checked after binding.

```
**API Response Object** 

[{
active: "Y"
activeYn: "Y"
category: "somehting"
id: 1
sortOrder: "1"
subProducts:"[
  {
   active: "Y"
   backEndName: "some1"
   checked: "true"
   displayName: "some1"
   id: 100
   sortOrder: "1"
  }
},
{
active: "Y"
activeYn: "Y"
category: "somehting"
id: 1
sortOrder: "1"
subProducts:"[
  {
   active: "Y"
   backEndName: "some2"
   checked: "true"
   displayName: "some2"
   id: 200
   sortOrder: "1"
  }
}
]

listproduct()
    {
    // let checked;
    // let active;
    this.http.getData("findproduct").subscribe((d) => {
    let mydata = d;
    this.result = mydata;
    console.log("@@@@@@@@@",this.result);
    this.selProducts = this.result;
    console.log("@@@@@@@@@",this.selProducts);
    for(var i =0 ;i<this.selProducts.length;i++){
    let p1 = this.selProducts[i].subProducts.filter(p => p.checked);
    // let p2 = p1.filter(p => p.checked == "false");
    let p2 = p1.filter(p => {
    if (p.checked) {
     this.checked = p.checked;
    var product = p.backEndName;
   this.active = p.active;
    this.newProduct.push({
    product: product,
    checked: (this.checked === 'true'),
    active :this.active
    });
    }
    });
    }

    },
    err => {
    this.result = err;
    });
    }
```

Can someone suggest me what is the best way to replace hard-coded object with real-time api?
so that rest of the functionality shouldn't break.

Comment: Does subproducts will have single entry ?? can you post the whole api response ,it will clear the picture

Comment: I updated my question with more clarity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create variable `products` and then assign result from your API and iterate `input` using `*ngFor`:

TypeScript:

```
products: any;

this.http.getData("findproduct").subscribe((d) => {
        products = d;
    },
    err => {
        this.result = err;
    });
```

As you have nested array, then you should use one `*ngFor` to iterate through `products` and another one for `subproducts`. So your HTML should look like this:

```
<div *ngFor="product in products">
    <div *ngFor="subProduct in product.subProducts">
        <input name="product-{{subProduct?.id}}"
              [(ngModel)]="subProduct?.checked"
              #fooInput>
    </div>        
</div>
```

Comment: It's array object so again i need to loop through to get the data right? for each object i have subProducts available.

Answer (score 1):

The mistakes are many and the code is hard to read. I suggest you take a step back and simplify things. Here's the approach I suggest that you take and also some comments on how to write things.

```
export class YourComponent implements OnInit {
  selProducts: any[];
  newProduct: any[];

  constructor(private productsService: ProductsService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.findProduct().subscribe(this.listProduct);
  }

  findProduct = (): Observable<any[]> =>
    this.productsService.getData("findproduct");

  listProduct = products => {
    this.selProducts = products;
    this.selProducts.forEach(product => {
      let p1 = product.subProducts.filter(p => p.checked);

      this.newProduct = p1.map(item => ({
        product: item.backEndName,
        checked: item.checked === "true",
        active: item.active
      }));
    });
  };
}

// Rename your service to something meaningful like ProductsService and move getData there
// Everything is data. Rename getData to getProducts
// result and selProducts contain the same data. use one
// you are not using `p2` somewhere else therefore it's not needed
// you already filtered in `p1` the items that are checked, there is no need to do it again
// by doing `p1.filter` and `if (p.checked) ...`
```